Is the product of two NONZERO elements independently drawn from a prime field uniformly distributed?
Let $\mathbb{Z}_p$ be a prime field, $a, b$ be two random elements independently drawn from $\mathbb{Z}_p^*$, and $$
c = a* b \mod p,$$ is $c$ uniformly random? and why?
How is this question related to the discrete-log assumption? Because if $a =b$, then my understanding is that the discrete-log assumption asserts $$ c =a^n \mod p$$ is indeed uniformly random.


Let $\mathbb{Z}_p$ be a prime field, $a, b$ be two random elements independently drawn from $\mathbb{Z}_p^*$, and $$
c = a* b \mod p,$$ is $c$ uniformly random?

No; if either $a = 0$ or $b = 0$, then $c = 0$.  Out of the $p^2$ possible pairs $(a, b)$, that gives $2p-1$ pairs that results in 0.  As the probability of each possible pair is equal, that is, $p^{-2}$, that gives a probability of a 0 output to be $2/p - 1/p^2$, which is larger than the probability $1/p$ it would have if $c$ was uniformly distributed.
Now, if we modify the distribution so that $a, b$ were uniformly and independently distributed over nonzero values, then it turns out that $c$ would be uniformly distributed over nonzero values.

Because if $a =b$, then my understanding is that the discrete-log assumption asserts $$ c =a^n \mod p$$ is indeed uniformly random.

Well, I don't know what $a=b$ has to do with it, and that assertion would appear to be unrelated to the discrete-log problem.  However, if $n$ (which you have not specified) is relatively prime to $p-1$, then yes, $c$ would be uniformly distributed (from the simple observation that $a^n \bmod p$ is a permutation in that case), and if $n$ is not relatively prime to $p-1$, then it is not.

$a, b$ are independently drawn from $\mathbb{Z}_p^{*}$, not $\mathbb{Z}_p$, so they are not zero.

"Now, if we modify the distribution so that a,b
were uniformly and independently distributed over nonzero values, then it turns out that c
would be uniformly distributed over nonzero values", Why?

@Jason: oops, I missed the *.  And, in that case, for any value $c$, there are exactly $p-1$ pairs $(a, b)$ s.t. $ab = c \bmod p$.  There are $(p-1)^2$ such pairs total, and so the probability for any such pair is exactly $(p-1) / (p-1)^2 = (p-1)^{-1}$.  Actually, it holds if we assume that one of the two (say, $a$) is uniform and independent of $b$; the distribution of $b$ can be anything.

Thanks, just try to visualize what you said: think of the group table of $\mathbb{Z}_p^{*}$, there is only one $c$ in each column and each row, so $c$ is uniformly random!

@Jason: yup. that is exactly correct.  And, it's not only true for prime fields, it is true for any finite field.

No. For example, let $a$ be a uniformly sampled element and let $b=a$ in which case $c=a^2\mod p$ is a quadratic residue and only half of the elements of $\mathbb Z_p^\times$ are quadratic residues.
You may wish to rephrase the question using the word "independent".
This question is not related to whether the discrete logarithm is hard to compute.
